# PHP-сервисы для проверки знаний

Tags: php

Изучаю PHP. Хотелось бы теорию закреплять практикой. Если какие-нибудь сервисы для проверки знаний? Чтобы можно было выполнять тестовые задания.

Comment: quizful.net

Answer (score 2):

Немного из моих закладок:

- [Zend Certification Exam](http://zend-php.appspot.com/questions_list)
- [Вопросы собеседований](http://www.quizful.net/interview/php)
- [Yet another test for PHP/MySQL/Linux](http://php.feedme.ru/index.php)
- [Brainbench](http://brainbench.com/xml/bb/common/testcenter/consumer/testcenter.xml) (keyword - PHP)